# Cannot resolve ConfirmActivity and findViewById in Adapter Class

Tags: android

I want to show a popupwindow as user clicks on the list items. I use  `initiatePopWindow()` in Adapter Class of my fragment. How can I resolve `findViewById` and `ConfirmActivity` ?

```
private void initiatePopupWindow() {
        try {
            //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ConfirmActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_addword,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
            pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 470, true);
            // display the popup in the center
            pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            TextView WordPop = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView PartsPop = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            TextView DescPop = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            TextView SentPop = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            WordPop.setText(list.getWord());
            PartsPop.setText(list.getParts());
            DescPop.setText(list.getDesc());
            SentPop.setText(list.getDesc());
            ImageButton cancelButton = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            //makeBlack(cancelButton);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the the activity context from the fragment to your adapter while creating your adapter instance.

Since you already have got the context in your adapter. 
Try this -

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
//Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_addword,(ViewGroup)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
```

Comment: since i'm new to this can you give an example.

Comment: Post the code where you are instantiating your adapter.

Comment: db = new WordBookHandler(getActivity());

        wordList = db.getAllWords();

        adapter = new WordBookAdapter(getActivity(), wordList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Paste your WordBookAdapter  constructor code. You already have the context there .

Comment: public WordBookAdapter(Activity activity, List<WordsData> contacts){

        this.activity = activity;
        this.wordList = contacts;
    }

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() method of fragment returns context so it can be used to pass context to the adapter like this -

first pass context to the adapter in its constructor as a parameter.
this can be done by using getActivity() method the fragment so initialize your adapter in the fragment as -

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(),YourOtherParameters...);
```

then in adapter constructor should look like

```
//global
Context context;

public YourAdapter(Context context,YourOtherParameters...) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

then use this context to inflate view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_addword,(ViewGroup)context.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
```